# Javascritp export/import constant object wrap the import in another object

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Greeting

I'm having a bit of trouble with some constant. Here is the situation

*constant_folder/index.js*

```
export const typieTypes = {
   TYPE_A: 'typea',
   TYPE_B: 'typeb',
};
```

*file_that_import*

```
import { typieTypes } from 'constant_folder';
```

The result is that typieTypes value according to developer tools is an object like this

```
typieTypes: {
   typieTypes:{/*correct values*/},
   someotherprops,
};
```

We were following this pattern that somehow work before because if when typieTypes is deconstructed we get the correct values, but once we tried to use Object.values(typieType)
we get undefined.

So yeah, we definitely are missing something here, and we weren't careful enough to see this before. What are we missing? Which technique/method could be a better approach. Because maybe we are trying to hard in order to have better practices.

Thank in advance.

Comment: Post the code, where you try to run `Object.values(typieType)`.

Comment: I think it's `import { typieTypes as typieTypes } from 'constant_folder';`, isn't it? more info here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import

Comment: @admcfajn The alias is optional, if you don't want to rename it you can omit it.

Comment: Where do those `someotherprops` come from? This is really weird, they definitely shouldn't be there. Can you show us how you are transpiling/bundling/loading those modules?

Comment: I can't post the object right now. I think, not sure, because according to docs these approach is interpreted as a class. I understand we are doing it wrong. But to be honest I'm trying to understand why. I'll update with the developer tool console log as soon as I can

Comment: @Bergi ah, so that'd just give you `alias: { typieTypes:{/*correct values*/} }`, right... what about eport default instead of naming the Object? `const typieTypes = () => {}
export default typieTypes;`

Comment: @admcfajn No, the code that the OP has posted is correct (expected to work). There must be something else going on.

Comment: what are you using to compile your build? [raulricardo21](https://stackoverflow.com/users/284136/raulricardo21), webpack? are you using a js-framework &/or any specific packages?

Comment: This are the extra prop  __esModule: true, __proto__: Object

Comment: And as per Object.values(typieType) is [{…}]. Which is logic, because the import does the wrap as describe in the post

Comment: @raulricardo21 Ah, yes, so you are transpiling *index.js*, this is a normal backward-compatible namespace object for use with older module systems. However, it also means that you are either transpiling *file_that_import* in a wrong manner, that the code you've shown is not your real one and you're actually using `import * as typieTypes from …`, or that the specifier `'constant_folder'` does not resolve to *index.js*. Please show us your transpiler/bundler/execution configuration.